# Delete Message from Telegram Group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working application that integrates with telegram and I had issue 
I create group and have admin on it and bot  I add bot that I can get messages update from the group chat problem is when I delete message from group chat by admin is should not be showing here

https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789token/getUpdates/

but I get all message history even I delete them any idea of what's is wrong?

Comment: There are 2 types of deletions of messages of chats! One you only delete msg from your client. Another is to completely deleting of the message. Update your telegram client (android, desktop,... ), the when you try to delete the message, it asks you if it should delete the message for other users too or not?

Comment: i need completely delete it

Comment: Is it still shown in the group? I could imagine that it´s still mentioned under `getupdates` because you made an update.

Comment: @creyD when i do getupdate its show even admin already delete it from group

Comment: Yeah I know because the method only tracks updates. The question is: is it still shown in the client?

Comment: @creyD yes  its show

Comment: @AdamKim Okay I´ve researched a bit and it looks like you just can´t delete the message for other group members - at the moment. Maybe the will add the feature later, but for now that´s it...

Comment: @tashakori It looks like this function only is available for normal chats and not for groups..

Comment: Look at this [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method